# Strategy to alter database synonym during normal production operation

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, scheduler

Currently I have a scenario that involves switching a synonym definition after the completion of a  scheduled job.  The job will create a table with an identifier of `even` or `odd` to correspond with the hour being even or odd.  What we are currently doing is this:

```
odd_job:  

create foo_odd ...  
replace foo_syn as foo_odd
```

and

```
even_job:  

create foo_even ...  
replace foo_syn as foo_even
```

What is happening is that during normal production the `foo_syn` is in a locked state.  So what we are looking for is a production capable way of swapping synonym definitions.

The question is how can we swap a synonym definition in a production level system with minimum user interruption in Oracle 10g?

**From the comments**

> Does foo_syn have any dependent objects?

No `foo_syn` is nothing more than a pointer to a table that I generate.  That is there are no procedures that need to be recompiled for this switch.

> That sounds like a really strange thing to do. Can you explain a bit
>   what that switch is for/how it is used?

Sure.  We have an application that interfaces with the database, the SQL that is executed from Java (business logic queries) has a reference to `foo_syn`.  Because of the dynamic nature of the data it is a guarantee that the hourly swap will give new results that are important as we try to get closer to real time.  Prior to this it was a once a day and be happy with it type scenario.

The reasoning for the swap is I do not want dynamic SQL (in terms of table names) to be a part of my application queries.  So therefore the database does a switch on the newer data set without changing the name of the synonym that is referenced as part of my application.

Comment: Does `foo_syn` have any dependent objects?

Comment: That sounds like a _really_ strange thing to do. Can you explain a bit what that switch is for/how it is used?

Comment: @Mat updated to answer

Comment: Thanks for the update by what I don't understand is why you'd be switching between to tables in the first place.

Comment: @Mat what would your recommendation be?  I don't really see a way to not swap between the tables.

Comment: I can't recommend anything, I have no idea _why_ you switch tables rather than updating data in a table.

Comment: @Mat ah that is what i was looking for.  It is computationally infeasible to do so, this approach was attempted and scuttled.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: I thought the only thing that would prevent CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM from working was having dependent objects. I have a clear memory of reading that, if you replaced a synonym *while it was in use*, the queries that started with references from the old synonym would finish *still* using the old synonym, and that new queries would immediately start using the new synonym. (I don't recall where I read that. Ask Tom, maybe.) Clearly I'm about to learn something new here.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' that is what we thought as well.  I think I have a solution that I will post here in the near future.  But what ended up happening is we had a scheduled job that would just hang indefinitely.

Comment: Does the scheduled job involve a stored procedure that uses foo_syn? I seem to recall that those kinds of situations might block if you replace a synonym.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' I suppose technically yes, the stored proc updates foo_Syn.

Comment: I thought that maybe replacing a synonym might invalidate stored procedures; they'd need to recompile. I'm not sure about that, though, and you seem to have covered that issue in your question. I couldn't find anything on point in the docs. In any case, that shouldn't make a job hang indefinitely. I'm out of ideas for the time being.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' for what it is worth I have posted a solution that we implemented.

Answer (score 3):

If using dynamic SQL is distasteful to you (and I'll quickly point out that in my experience dynamic SQL has never proved to be a performance issue, but YMMV) then a UNION query might be what you're looking for - something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM EVEN_DATA_TABLE
  WHERE TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH')) IN (0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12)
UNION ALL
SELECT *
  FROM ODD_DATA_TABLE
  WHERE TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH')) IN (1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11)
```

This also eliminates the need to have a periodic job to change the synonym as it's driven off of SYSDATE.

This makes the assumption that the columns in EVEN_DATA_TABLE and ODD_DATA_TABLE are the same.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: now that is an interesting implementation.  Oh I was more concerned about dynamic sql from a maintenance perspective, since it resides in a Java application.  Let me test this out and see what we can do about it.

Comment: Honestly, I don't like queries such as this.  If 'twas up to me I'd combine the two tables into one and add a column to differentiate between the 'odd' and 'even' data.  YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that we came up with is as follows:

1) Define a function that will return which set of tables you should be looking at:

```
  create or replace function which_synonym return varchar2 as  
  to_return varchar2(4) := NULL;  
  is_valid number :=- 1;  
  current_time number := to_number(to_char(sysdate,'HH'));    
  is_odd boolean := FALSE;  

BEGIN   
   if = mod(current_time,2)    -- it is an even time slot
   then    
      select success into is_valid  
      from success_table  
      where run='EVEN';    
   else    
      select success into is_valid  
      from success_table  
      where run='ODD';  
   end if;  
   if is_valid=0 and is_odd=TRUE  
   then to_Return ='ODD';  
   else  
     to_return='EVEN';    
   end if;  
   Return to_return;   
END which_synonym;
```

De Morgan's laws omitted for conciseness.

2) Configure the application procedures to take advantage of this flipping:

a)  Tokenize enumerated sql strings with a sequence that you want to match on:

```
select * from foo_&&&
```

b)  write the function that will replace this sequence:

```
 public String whichSynonym(String sql)  
 {  
   if(null==sql || "".equals(sql.trim()))  
   {  
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot process null or empty sql");
   }    
   String oddEven = "";
     //removed boilerplate  
     PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("Select which_synonym from dual");  
     statement.execute();  
     ResultSet results = statement.getResults();  
     while(results.next())  
     {
          oddEven=results.getString(1);  
     }    
     return sql.replace("&&&",oddEven);
 }
```